# Adding jQuery to Wordpress archive search

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

For all of the pages on a wordpress site I need the `.wrap {max-width: 100%;}` but for some reason this affects the archive search page differently and makes the results span the whole page. In short if I know where to add the jQuery, I can code it myself but I am having difficulty finding where exactly to put this code.

By archive results page I mean, when on a wordpress blog and the default archive widget with the dropdown menu is clicked, you choose a month and are forwarded onto a page for that month. This page displays the results, and on this page I need to bring the wrap `max-width` in.

I know it's probably more efficient to do with PHP but I am not comfortable with PHP yet so would prefer to just put a simple jQuery .CSS function in there.

Comment: max-width 100% seems kind of pointless, but regardless just change the html in the relevent template file

Comment: it was needed was certain pages because the way the template is built it made a margin on all the pages, the archive results page also uses the same template page as other pages on the site so it's not possible to just edit the template file, hence jQuery.

Comment: Well in order to only effect the archive page, you will need to use some conditional php code to only inject your jquery code on the correct page. So you will be writing php anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without JQuery. Add this in your header.php file before wp_head() function.

```
<?php if(is_archive()){ ?>
    <style type="text/css">
         .wrap {
             max-width: 70% !important; //Change this to whatever you want.
          }
    </style>
<?php } ?>
```